# What's the difference between '~' '$' and '-> ~' in Ubuntu shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

```
 ~ sh
$ dash
$ quit
dash: 1: quit: not found
$ bash
dblab@slave1-hadoop:~$ exit
exit
$ exit
$
```

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include you screenshot into this question instead of linking to one. Or, even better, copy the text from the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your default shell -> is zsh, when you enter sh, ubuntu default shell is dash, you can get it by

```
ls -l /bin/sh 
output:
/bin/sh -> /bin/dash
```

quit is not a command of dash, while you enter bash command, you enter a bash environment, exit is bash command, if you want get a same result you can change /bin/sh symbol link to /bin/bash.

Answer (score 0):

Both are shell prompts, one is `dash` the other is `bash`.  Both `bash` and `dash` can be set to have the same boot prompts, (not that you'd want to, but to show it can be done, which demonstrates the arbitrary nature of such prompts), by tweaking the  `$PS1` variable.  From `man bash`:

```
   PS1    The value of this parameter is expanded  (see  PROMPTING  below)
          and  used  as  the  primary prompt string.  The default value is
          ``\s-\v\$ ''.
   PS2    The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used  as
          the secondary prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.
   PS3    The value of this parameter is used as the prompt for the select
          command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above).
   PS4    The value of this parameter is expanded  as  with  PS1  and  the
          value  is  printed  before  each command bash displays during an
          execution trace.  The first character of PS4 is replicated  mul‐
          tiple  times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indi‐
          rection.  The default is ``+ ''.
```

Try running the `for` loop below in `dash` and `bash`, to print the various levels of prompts (between two colons to show the spaces).  Here's what `dash` shows:

```
for f in PS1 PS2 PS3 PS4 ; do eval echo :\$$f: ; done
:$ :
:> :
::
:+ :
```